# Android Download file from Link

Tags: java, android

I am trying to download file from one android mobile to other via Ip+port.
i can sucessfully download file from other mobile if i write the url in Web Browser of mobile.
the URL is like this

```
      http://172.20.99.238:9999/file/3/001_01.mp3
```

but i am unable to download this file via code

```
                    String downLoadLink = "http:/"+url+":9999/file/"+fileID+"/"+fileName;
            //downLoadLink = downLoadLink.replace(" ", "");
            Intent downloadIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            downloadIntent.setData(Uri.parse(downLoadLink));
            startActivity(downloadIntent);
```

Any Solution of this Problem

Comment: Did you check from debugging that downLoadLink has the correct value? (I think it is missing one /)

Comment: add / still the same problem :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are targeting at least API level 9 you should use the DownloadManager. I've been playing with it and works really nice avoiding to launch the browser and handles everything you need. Instead of copy pasting the code I'll give the following link:

http://www.vogella.com/blog/2011/06/14/android-downloadmanager-example/

Try using only onClick method for testing purpose. The rest of the code is just for getting an URI to the file.

Answer (score 1):

just use this code with internet permission in the manifest

```
        String servicestring = Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE;
        DownloadManager downloadmanager;
        downloadmanager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(servicestring);
        Uri uri = Uri
                .parse("your link to file");
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
        Long reference = downloadmanager.enqueue(request);
```